# How to optimize the finding of a specific string as part of a whole string in a large set of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, match, matching

I have two arrays of objects and I am trying to optimize the match between two strings that are part of those objects.

In worst case scenario I have to loop through the entire objects in the destination array.

Origin array:

```
[ {name: "banana 1"}, {name: "banana 2"}, {name: "monkey"}]
```

Destination array:

```
[ {title: "this is a banana 1"}, {title: "this doesnt matter"}, {title: "this also doesnt matter"} ]
```

I have to find match on the destination array for each element of the origin array using regex.

In this case I would have only a match:

banana 1 -> this is a banana 1

I think there isn't a better and faster way than two loops, one for iterating the origin array and the second loop inside the first loop to iterate through all destinations in order to find a match for each origin object in the destination array.

Is there a some way of improving this? I would like to optimize it since my arrays have a lot of elements. I have been try to find how indexes with like expressions are implemented in postgres, maybe that could help me in some way.

Comment: do you have to match index wise?

Comment: what do you mean? I didn't got it sorry

Comment: your match in both arrays at index zero. could it be, that the match is at index zero in the first array and at index 1000 in the second array?

Comment: yeah yeah that's totally possible, in worst case scenario (to find matches of all elements in first array) I would need to loop the entire second array the amount of times equal to the first array size

Comment: do you have only one match?

Comment: yes firstly I sort the first array using the string length, this means that strings with higher length appear first than a string smaller length. And then while I am iterating the second array (because I explained it wrong, I start by iterating the second array and then use the first array), I pick the first item from the first array, this will be the one with higher length

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with an underscore `_` (it could be a `Symbol` as well) as property to denote a searchstring end.

To get the word of the first array, you couls iterate until the length (optimised with the sortes search string length) and check in another loop all characters. If finally found the end indicator, you found a words.

```js
let shortest = Number.MAX_VALUE;

const
    values = [{ name: "banana 1" }, { name: "banana 2" }, { name: "monkey" }],
    destinations = [{ title: "this is a banana 1##with some more text" }, { title: "this doesnt matter" }, { title: "this also doesnt matter" }],
    trie = values.reduce((t, { name }) => {
        if (shortest > name.length) shortest = name.length;
        [...name].reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, t)._ = true;
        return t;
    }, {}),
    result = destinations.map(({ title }) => {
        for (let i = 0, l = title.length - shortest + 1; i < l; i++) {
            let p = trie;
            for (let j = i; j < title.length; j++) {
                if (!(p = p[title[j]])) break;
                if (p._) return title.slice(i, j + 1);
            }
        }
        return '';
    });
console.log(shortest);
console.log(result);
console.log(trie);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```